# How can I connect to a Cloud SQL instance in a different GCP project from BigQuery using an external data source?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

Is there is way to connect to the Cloud SQL instance which is in a different GCP project. For example, in Project A the cloud sql instance is created in US region, and I want to bring the SQL data to the BigQuery in project B using an external data source connection.

There is GCP documentation on how to create the cloud sql connection but no information regarding cross project access.

Comment: You can't do this for now.